# Delete rows that have cell with specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete every row that has cell with `?` value in it.
I do not know where `?` value is (i do not know name of the column).
Any idea how to do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4,6,"?",3],
                   'B': ["?",3,5,1,4],
                   'C': [13,5,61,5, "?"]})
```

Desired output:

```
   A  B   C
0  4  3   5
1  6  5  61
```

Comment: `df = df[df.ne('?').all(1)]`?

Comment: Funny how hard it is to find a dupe for something this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
df=df.replace('?',np.nan)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
    A   B   C
1   4.0 3.0 5.0
2   6.0 5.0 61.0
```

For more information please see [`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could do :

```py
df[df == "?"] = None
df = df.dropna(axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line version :

```
result = df.replace('?', pd.np.nan).dropna()
```